# Setting streetview POV heading throws an error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

In my application I have a Google map and the related Streetview in two different divs.
Streetview values of POV are stored inside the database, as a packed string, for example:
`34.094522, -118.31127700000002,-141,0,1`
The first two numbers are the lat and lang values, then I have heading, pitch and zoom.
Once the page is loaded, I set the POV inside the panorama in this way:

```
var pov = <field with saved values>.value.split(",");
PANORAMA.setPov({
    heading: (pov[2] ? pov[2].toInt() : 0),
    pitch: (pov[3] ? pov[3].toInt() : 0),
    zoom: (pov[4] ? pov[4].toInt() : 1)
});
```

This used to work fine until ~15 days ago, then I started to have the following error in Firebug:
[image: Firebug error]

After (several) tries, I tracked down the issue to the `heading` value: it works only if it's between -10 and 10 + (360 * < number of full rotations >), so -10/10, 350/370 and so on.
Looking at the docs, it should accept any values starting from 0; moreover, when I rotate the POV I update my location field getting the heading, pitch and zoom values:

```
var heading = PANORAMA.getPov().heading.toInt();
var pitch   = PANORAMA.getPov().pitch.toInt();
var zoom    = PANORAMA.getPov().zoom.toInt();
```

While executing the above code, I can see that the heading can get any value, indicating the number of degrees from the true north (as I expected to be).
Any ideas why I'm getting this error and why it only accepts values between -10 and 10?

Comment: Are you using the [experimental version of the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)? A [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be useful.

Comment: Same error here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple , use the release-version: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3

Comment: @Dr.Molle Can you please turn your comment into an answer, so I can accept it and build a statue in your honor?

Comment: [issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7098)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been an API-update last week.

I guess you are using the experimental version, at least the error occurs also with the demo used in the documentation(which also uses the experimental version):  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple

There are several bugs in the new experimental version, this obviously is another bug.

[issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7098)

Use the release-version instead(recommended in production) : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3